# Flask and IIS8.5 windows authentication

Tags: flask, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

I managed to setup windows authentication for my flask application with IIS 8.5. (Flask app runs frontend angular and also the api's needed by it). Everything works fine when i access the machine using the ip address and the port ie. the browser asks for a username and password prompt and api's work fine after authentication. But when I use the computersname.domain to access the page, there is no authentication and I'm automatically redirected(which I understand is auto-login because the requesting machine and the server are in the same domain). 
The main problem is that when I use IP address to access the api's I was able to capture the username of the logged-on user using the flask variable `request.environ['REMOTE_USER']`. But when the computername and domain is used, I am not able to capture the username. How do I capture it?

Comment: are you able to successfully access the site after entering the username and password with the domain name on a remote machine? which authentication is enabled in your site? did you disable the anonymous authentication? please check the iis log for the error.

Comment: Yes I am successfully able to login using the credentials. Only windows authentication is enabled rest all is disabled(including anonymous authentication). Also, there is no error when using the computer name and domain name to login. I'm able to login without any need of credential! Just that I'm not able to capture the username of the logged in user.